# Using Scala groupBy(), from method fetchUniqueCodesForARootCode(). I want to get a map from rootCodes to lists of uniqueCodes

Tags: scala, group-by, concurrency, user-defined-functions, future

*I want to to return `Future[Map[String, List[String]]]` from `fetchUniqueCodesForARootCode` method*

```
    import scala.concurrent._
    import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global  
    case class DiagnosisCode(rootCode: String, uniqueCode: String, description: Option[String] = None)

    object Database {

      private val data: List[DiagnosisCode] = List(
        DiagnosisCode("A00", "A001", Some("Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae")),
        DiagnosisCode("A00", "A009", Some("Cholera, unspecified")),
        DiagnosisCode("A08", "A080", Some("Rotaviral enteritis")),
        DiagnosisCode("A08", "A083", Some("Other viral enteritis"))
      )
    
      def getAllUniqueCodes: Future[List[String]] = Future {
        Database.data.map(_.uniqueCode)
      }


      def fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCode(uniqueCode: String): Future[Option[DiagnosisCode]] = Future {
        Database.data.find(_.uniqueCode.equalsIgnoreCase(uniqueCode))
      }
    }
```

*getAllUniqueCodes returns all unique codes from data List.*

*fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCode returns DiagnosisCode when uniqueCode matches.*

- From fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCodes, I am returningFuture[List[DiagnosisCode]] using getAllUniqueCodes() and fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCode(uniqueCode).*

  ```
    def fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCodes: Future[List[DiagnosisCode]] = {

      val xa: Future[List[Future[DiagnosisCode]]] = Database.getAllUniqueCodes.map { (xs: 
          List[String]) =>
        xs.map { (uq: String) =>
          Database.fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCode(uq)
        }
      }.map(n =>
          n.map(y=>
            y.map(_.get))) 
    }

    xa.flatMap {
    listOfFuture =>
      Future.sequence(listOfFuture)
   }}
  ```

> Now, `def fetchUniqueCodesForARootCode` should return `Future[Map[String, List[DiagnosisCode]]]` using `fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCodes` and `groupBy`

**Here is the method**

```
def fetchUniqueCodesForARootCode: Future[Map[String, List[String]]] = {
  fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCodes.map { x =>
    x.groupBy(x => (x.rootCode, x.uniqueCode))
  }
}
```

*Need to get the below result from `fetchUniqueCodesForARootCode`*:-

`A00 -> List(A001, A009), H26 -> List(H26001, H26002), B15 -> List(B150, B159), H26 -> List(H26001, H26002)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to decode from the question description, what the problem is. But if I understood correctly, you want to get a map from `rootCode`s to lists of `uniqueCode`s.

The `groupBy` method takes a function that for every element returns its key. So first you have to group by the `rootCode`s and then you have to use `map` to get the correct values.

`groupBy` definition: https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/collection/IterableOps.html#groupBy-f68

scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KacperFKorban/PL1X3joNT3qNOTm6OQ3VUQ